# Append a value to a property in shell script through ANT

Tags: string, shell, ant

Need some help with ant and shell script.
I need to open a shell script and append some value to a property of the shell script using ant.

Below is the code written by me using ant-

```
<property name="args" value="${ARGS}"/>         
<replaceregexp file="abc.sh"
match="ARGS=(.*)"
replace="ARGS=${args} some_value=true" 
byline="true"
flags="i" />
```

The issue I am facing is the value of ARGS in abc.sh is in the format ARGS="value"

The output of this code is -
ARGS="value" some_value=true

The expected output is -
ARGS="value some_value=true"

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you can use just `<replaceregexp>` to get what you want. There's no need for the `${args}` or `${ARGS}` properties.

In XML, attribute values can be surrounded by either quotation marks (`"`) or single quotes (`'`). In the following example...

```
match="..."
replace="..."
```

...becomes...

```
match='...'
replace='...'
```

The quotation marks have been replaced with single quotes. Using single quotes allows us to easily use quotation marks in both the `match` and `replace` attributes of `<replaceregexp>`:

```
<replaceregexp
    file="abc.sh"
    match='ARGS="([^"]*)"'
    replace='ARGS="\1 some_value=true"'
    byline="true" />
```

The regular expression `ARGS="([^"]*)"` will match strings starting with `ARGS="`. Then, characters that are **not** quotation marks (`"`) will be matched and stored in capture group 1. Finally, the regular expression will match a trailing quotation mark.

In the `replace` attribute, the `\1` is replaced by the contents of capture group 1 from the `match` attribute.

Some test cases are below...

### Original abc.sh

```
IRRELEVANT_LINE_1="irrelevantValue1"
ARGS="value"
IRRELEVANT_LINE_2="irrelevantValue2"
```

### Replaced abc.sh

```
IRRELEVANT_LINE_1="irrelevantValue1"
ARGS="value some_value=true"
IRRELEVANT_LINE_2="irrelevantValue2"
```